How do I get firefox back after I accidentally used terminal to make it stop working
When I try to enter Firefox web browser all it does is show up on the top left on the screen, but then it goes away without opening the website.
More information: The reason I was using terminal was because I was trying to delete archive manager, but instead I made Firefox Ubuntu software, and chromium web browser stop working.
Output of firefox when run in a terminal:
/var/lib/snapd has ‘other’ write 40777

After I typed stat / it said:
  File: /
  Size: 4096      Blocks: 8     Io Block: 4096   directory
Device: 10302h/66306d     Inode2.    Links: 19
Access: (0755/drwxr-x)  Uid: (  0/  root)
Access:2024-04-15 12:57:44. 155458333 -0500
Modify:2023-09-20 10:38:04.155458333 -0500
Change:2023-09-20 10:38:04.155458333 -0500
Birth: 2023-09-04.000000000 -0500


Run firefox in a terminal, I don't expect it to work but surely it should print an error message or something; once you get that error, please add it to the question by editing it.

I don’t know how I’m very new and I messed that up.

Can you expand on how you accidentally used the terminal to make it stop working.  What did you do, and what were you trying to do?  It's not a criticism; the information may just help people to help you out.

You said you used a terminal to do something to Firefox, what I'm suggesting you do is you literally write firefox in a terminal window and hit Enter, which will attempt to run Firefox but, at the same time, most likely, will print one or more error messages to the terminal; once that's happened, please copy paste those errors into the question so that we can see them.

It said$ /var/lib/snapd has ‘other’ write 40777

Ok, now please write this into the terminal: stat / but don't paste the output into a comment, please paste it into your question instead by clicking on this link

Ok, now try stat /var/lib/snapd; to be clear, that issue might be due to wrong permissions on some key folders, and I'm asking you to run stat on them to check if they indeed have the correct permissions assigned to them; so please add also the output of stat /var/lib/snapd to your question so that we can check on it as well (/ appears to be fine)

Once you've done it, leave a comment here mentioning me using @kos so I can get back at this, otherwise I may not notice.

Actually there's something missing in the output of stat / (there should be more stuff after Access: (0755/drwxr-x)  Uid: (  0/  root)), however I would say that it's unlikely the problem is there at this point, so for now just post the output of stat /var/lib/snapd

@Dan, If you can tell more detail about what you attempted when trying to delete archive manager, then people here might have a better clue to what actually happened.
